# Storing date and hour (without minutes and seconds) in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need to store dates with hours, but without minutes or seconds. That's because I want the data to be grouped by hour, and be able to insert with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...` if two events happen in the same hour.

I've seen some applications using a `DATETIME` field, and inserting with

`date("Y-m-d H") . ':00:00'`

is this the best practice or are there better solutions?

Comment: They are ads impressions, they may be millions in a single hour

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is good practice. Date/Times should be keep in date/time fields - thanks to that you can still use special date and time functions which is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your use case.

- If you need to ever query a specific `date` or specific `hour` entry. You should use separate `DATE` and `TIME` (or `TINYINT`) column types, with a `UNIQUE INDEX` on both columns and not a `DATETIME` column type.
- If you only ever need the date with the hour a `DATETIME` column with a `UNIQUE INDEX` would be suitable.

I prefer to ensure the resulting data is correct by accepting the full date as a column. This makes it easier for querying on for reporting purposes, etc, as well as for standardizing the other column values.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `test` (
    -> `my_date` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    -> `my_hour` TIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    -> `full_date` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    -> `duplicates` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    -> UNIQUE INDEX `my_date_my_hour` (`my_date`, `my_hour`)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.18 sec)
```

Then instead of formatting the insert value in PHP or declaring  the individual column values, format your query's input data, using the `full_date` column as a reference.

```
mysql> INSERT INTO test (full_date, my_date, my_hour) 
    -> VALUES('2016-04-01 20:30:22', DATE(full_date), TIME_FORMAT(full_date, '%H:00:00'))
    -> ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    -> duplicates = duplicates+1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)
```

If you use `TINYINT` for `my_hour` column, change the insert value to `TIME_FORMAT(full_date, '%H')`.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test;
+------------+----------+---------------------+------------+
| my_date    | my_hour  | full_date           | duplicates |
+------------+----------+---------------------+------------+
| 2016-04-01 | 20:00:00 | 2016-04-01 20:30:22 |          0 |
+------------+----------+---------------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Insert another entry changing the Minute and Second, to cause duplicates to be incremented.

```
mysql> INSERT INTO test (full_date, my_date, my_hour) 
    -> VALUES('2016-04-01 20:32:20', DATE(full_date), TIME_FORMAT(full_date, '%H:00:00'))
    -> ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    -> duplicates = duplicates+1;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.04 sec)
```

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test;
+------------+----------+---------------------+------------+
| my_date    | my_hour  | full_date           | duplicates |
+------------+----------+---------------------+------------+
| 2016-04-01 | 20:00:00 | 2016-04-01 20:30:22 |          1 |
+------------+----------+---------------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then you can concatenate the `my_date` and `my_hour` columns into a single column value to accept in PHP.

```
mysql> SELECT *, CONCAT(my_date, 'T', my_hour) as date_hour FROM test;
+------------+----------+---------------------+------------+---------------------+
| my_date    | my_hour  | full_date           | duplicates | date_hour           |
+------------+----------+---------------------+------------+---------------------+
| 2016-04-01 | 20:00:00 | 2016-04-01 20:30:22 |          1 | 2016-04-01T20:00:00 |
+------------+----------+---------------------+------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then in PHP you can format the resulting recordsets.

```
$date = new DateTime($row['date_hour']);
$timestamp = strtotime($row['date_hour']);
//or
$date = new DateTime($row['my_date'] . 'T' . $row['my_hour']);
$timestamp = strtotime($row['my_date'] . 'T' . $row['my_hour']);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group things by hour and you want it to be performant create a derivative column that stores the time value in hours since epoch. Normally that's as easy as dividing the epoch time in seconds by 3600.

You'll have a schema like this:

```
event_time DATETIME,
event_hour INT
```

Then add values like this:

```
INSERT INTO ... (..., event_time, event_hour)
  VALUES (..., '2016-05-30 13:00:00', 406841)
```

You can set a `UNIQUE` constraint on the `event_hour` column.

Answer (score 0):

From my best of know it will better to store date in integer format like epoch time because 
1. it will store every thing like date month year hours minutes seconds.
2. While searching using epoch time it will faster because integer comparison is faster than string comparison.

[Use of epochtime in MySQL](http://www.easysolutionweb.com/sql-pl-sql/mysql-unix-timestamp-and-from-unixtime)